# Regex to pull value from middle of file path

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out how to pull the following string out of a folder path... I want to pull COMPANY_NAME from the below folder path.  Is there a way to use REGEX to pull string between 2nd and 3rd backslash?

Example:

\10.20.3.23\S$\COMPANY_NAME\Main_5e08a942f39a430db0b081736a3f1881\C_VOL-b002.spf

Comment: Try this: `\\[^\\]*\\[^\\]*\\([^\\]*)\\.*`

Comment: Hello @hacker315  I left off the leading backslash, should look like \\10.20.3.23\S$\COMPANY_NAME\Main_5e08a942f39a430db0b081736a3f1881\C_VOL-b002.spf

Comment: Then try this: `\\\\[^\\]*\\[^\\]*\\([^\\]*)\\.*`

Comment: @hacker315 I put that into an online regex editor and it pulls the entire line not just the COMPANY_NAME

Comment: `^(?:\\[^\\]*){3}\\\K([^\\]+)` - cf. https://regex101.com/r/pPqpnv/1

Comment: What are you doing this in? It may be simpler to split on backslash. eg. powershell: `("\this\is\my\path".Split("\\"))[4]`

Comment: That did it!  Thanks took your powershell and spitting suggestion and @hacker thanks for your suggestions!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this `(?(DEFINE)(?<urlPart>[^\\\s]+))\\\\(?&urlPart)\\(?&urlPart)\\\K(?&urlPart)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/UjzDnt/1)

It will match the desired part of the URL you are after. Things to note:

- The url does not need to start at the beginning of the string (if you require this add ^ after the define group)
- It will match many urls in the same string
- It will match even if there is no file name
- White space will invalidate the match
- See the demo for details

If you were wondering it uses [subroutine definitions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) to reuse parts of the regex.